# converting from string to decimal eliminates spl characters in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

Below is my code that is used to read the open office spreadsheet data and insert into database i have three columns that are of type string and four columns that are of type decimals so i am converting them to decimals from fourth column using below code

```
//newly added
if (iCol > 2)
   {
       string value = ((XText)oSheet.getCellByPosition(iCol, iRow)).getString();
       decimal vv = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
       drNew[i] = vv;
       i++;
   }
   else
   {
       drNew[i] = ((XText)oSheet.getCellByPosition(iCol, iRow)).getString();//old code
       i++;//old code
   }
```

but the problem is along with decimal i have special characters like $ and , as shown below

```
$25,529.98
$1,61,800.52
$0.00
$7,252.80
```

but with my above code the insertion happens as shown below

```
25529.9800
161800.5200
0.0000
7252.8000
```

Also i had tried the below code

```
     `if (iCol > 2) 
      { 
     string value = ((XText)oSheet.getCellByPosition(iCol, iRow)).getString(); 
     if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number)) 
      { 
      drNew[i] = value.ToString(); i++; 
      } 

  }
```

` but it is not at all going into the if condition

***How can i insert the data as it is with $ . and , in database.***

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy about this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Payment", typeof(decimal));
```

That shows, that you are using the right type to store your data.

But you have a deep misunderstandig in **how** a value is stored.

Whether you see `$25,529.98` or `25529.9800` is just a matter of formatting the output. The stored value is a binary bit map, a human reader hardly could interpret. Whenever such a value is presented to you or through your application, this is *transformed* (=*formatted*) into a human readable **string**. You should be happy, that your format is not stored together with the value!

This formatting issue is something your presentation layer / reporting engine should do as final step.

Comment: Yes! You should be happy about this! Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: @abc I do not get this... My suggestion: Edit your question, **reduce it!** (one or two examples are enough), reduce the code to the point. I think, that you have a misconception of a numeric/decimal value and its textual presentation...

Comment: @abc As it looks, your difficulties occur, when you try to parse the string value taken from an Excel cell to decimal. You might either [pass a format with `TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx), or read the value as number or use Excel's abilities to cast the string to an appropriate type. You might add an invisible column besides your values, where you use Excel formulas to transform the text to a *real value*.

Comment: @abc check the link. TryParse has got a third parameter. Try to specify the format.

Comment: @abc Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!